# Is there a way to define the Bootstrap5 relatedTarget property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-modal, dom-events, bootstrap-5

I'm working with Bootstrap 5's Modal component and wanted to implement the following code from the documentation into TypeScript which I am new to *instead* of JavaScript.

```
var exampleModal = document.getElementById('exampleModal')
exampleModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // Button that triggered the modal
  var button = event.relatedTarget
  // Extract info from data-bs-* attributes
  var recipient = button.getAttribute('data-bs-whatever')
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here
  // and then do the updating in a callback.
  //
  // Update the modal's content.
  var modalTitle = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-title')
  var modalBodyInput = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-body input')

  modalTitle.textContent = 'New message to ' + recipient
  modalBodyInput.value = recipient
})
```

Example originates from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)

The hurdle I can't seem to get around is the property `relatedTarget` not being defined since it is a custom property from the Bootstrap code. I'm not sure if there is an appropriate interface I can use and the compiler will recognize (maybe there's a package that does that already), or if I need to make a global declaration to avoid the issue beforehand.

Comment: is this relevant? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/edit/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L515

Comment: Yes! Looks like relatedTarget is a property available in the MouseEvent interface. Thank you